# NLTK - AttributeError: module 'nltk' has no attribute 'data'

Tags: python-3.x, import, nltk

I used `nltk` in my code for a few days, but now, when I try to `import nltk`, I get the error:

```
File "C:\Users\Nada\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\plaintext.py", line 42, in PlaintextCorpusReader 
sent_tokenizer=nltk.data.LazyLoader(

AttributeError: module 'nltk' has no attribute 'data'
```

I installed `weka package` yesterday but it didn't work, I don't know in this has anything to do with that...

I tried to update it, but the error keeps showing up.

Comment: Did you name your script as `nltk.py`?

Comment: No i didn't. Last time i reinstalled nltk and it worked, but now i get the same error and reinstalling didn't help. :(

Answer (score 19):

I was getting the same issue. I uninstalled and re-installed it completely. it worked for me.

```
pip uninstall nltk
```

Then I installed it again

```
pip install -U nltk
```

Ref: http://www.nltk.org/install.html

Answer (score 13):

Shutting down the kernel and restarting fixed my issue.

Comment: Agree with this, I just restarted my kernel and everything works fine

Answer (score 7):

I performed the same steps as above and it worked :

1. Uninstall - `pip uninstall nltk`
2. Install - `pip install -U nltk`
3. Close Spyder
4. Re-open Spyder.
5. To check if nltk is working - in Ipython Console type:`**import nltk**`

Answer (score 3):

Just to add more information. I'm facing this issue when I have two notebooks and one of them is actively using NLTK. When I try to import NLTK on the other notebook, I get that error. So my answer is to look at other processes and make sure that nothing is using NLTK in the background.

Answer (score 3):

i get the same issue, restarting the kernel fixed my issue

Answer (score 3):

For Kaggle kernel restarting it fixed the issue.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, check that your solution was not posted in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62117367/7709603) before posting it.

Answer (score 0):

I performed the same steps as above and it worked :

1. Uninstall - `pip uninstall nltk`
2. Install - `pip install -U nltk`
3. Close Spyder
4. Re-open Spyder.
5. Try putting the name of the model as a parameter of the download() function. e.g.

   ```
   import nltk
   nltk.download('punkt')
   ```

Comment: I did the re installation step and I checked about punkt It s ok, howvever the same error. What would be the problem? Thanks in advance.